# Showing a folder in the menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Is it possible to "have a folder" on the menu bar, so that when you click it shows its content ?

Comment: As shows its content you mean opening Finder with that folder? Or the menu item should list files somehow?

Comment: Is XMenu ->  https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13797/xmenu something you're looking for?

Comment: oh that's nice ! It looks like it.. trying

Comment: That's exactly it. Can you put this as an answer ? Thank you for the tip !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free tool called XMenu does this kind of thing. It was written and is available from [Devon Technologies](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) You can get it from [macupdate](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13797/xmenu) or on the [AppStore](https://apps.apple.com/pl/app/xmenu/id419332741?l=pl&mt=12).

[image: XMenu screenshot]

Comment: thanks you. ps.. is macupdate better than the App Store (I imagine it provides statistics ?)

Comment: Oh I didn't know it's on the AppStore as well. I don't know which one is better. Probably AppStore is "safer" (?).

Comment: ok, I was wondering if there was something special. thank you !

Comment: This is also available from the authors https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware

Comment: Macupdate makes money from adverts and tracking you and in the past has had adware see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacUpdate AppleStore will provide automnatic updtaes when they occur

Comment: Stay away from Macupdate: get it from DevonTech's website, or the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 3):

I made a free app for this called [Folder Peek](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1615988943).

[image: Screenshot]

---

It is similar to XMenu, but more powerful:

- You can choose any folder and as many as you want, not just a few predefined ones and a single custom folder.
- Each folder can be individually customized.
- Sandboxed app (more secure).
- Custom menu bar icon.
- File preview.
- Copy, share, and drag & drop a file.
- View and copy image/video dimensions.
- Open a file or folder in a specific app.
- Sort files by date created, date modified, date accessed, date added, and kind.
- Show the menu using a custom global keyboard shortcut.
- Limit the number of items shown in the menu.
- Shortcuts support.